# Sort time array from time now in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

Hi im trying to create a sort from time array,
result should be the nearest time(from array) of the current time

Example :

> ```
> const current_time = new Date() //sample 13:40
> ```

Time Array:

```
const data = ["06:30:00",
            "09:00:00",
            "11:30:00",
            "13:00:00",
            "14:30:00",
            "15:00:00",
            "17:30:00" ,
            "18:00:00"]
```

Call function to sort

> ```
> const result = createTimeSort(current_time , data)
> ```

Expected result

```
//Sample 1 Time 13:40
["13:00:00","14:30:00","15:00:00","17:30:00","18:00:00","06:30:00","09:00:00","11:30:00"]

// Sample 2 Time 17:50
// ["17:30:00","18:00:00","06:30:00","09:00:00","11:30:00","13:00:00","14:30:00","15:00:00"]
```

Comment: the general pattern of sort-by-distance is `a.sort((x, y) => distance_to(x) - distance_to(y))`. The only thing that remains is to code the `distance_to` function.

Comment: yes actually can be similar idea

Comment: do you want the given result or the sorting by delta of time?

Comment: the sorted result

Comment: any result would be sorted ...

Comment: Is the input always sorted in ascending order?

Comment: the result is stated on the question. if sorting by delta time will come up with stated result its good already

Comment: @adiga yes  ascending order is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to get the wanted result, you could sort the array and take a new array with offset for the wanted time.

```js
function createTimeSort(time, [...array]) {
    array.sort();
    let index = array.findIndex(s => s > time);
    index -= index && 1;
     
    return index
        ? [...array.slice(index), ...array.slice(0, index)]
        : array;
}

const
  data = ["06:30:00", "09:00:00", "11:30:00", "13:00:00", "14:30:00", "15:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00"];

console.log(...createTimeSort('13:40', data));
// ["13:00:00", "14:30:00", "15:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "06:30:00", "09:00:00", "11:30:00"]

console.log(...createTimeSort('17:50', data));
// ["17:30:00", "18:00:00", "06:30:00", "09:00:00", "11:30:00", "13:00:00", "14:30:00", "15:00:00"]

console.log(...createTimeSort('17:29', data));
console.log(...createTimeSort('17:30:00', data));
```

Comment: nice almost there but '17:30' is not correct :)

Comment: @Jakegarbo, you could take the full time with seconds.

Comment: Nice, elegantly efficient solution. You can still get a performance gain by using [`_.sortedIndex`](https://underscorejs.org/#sortedIndex) to find `index` by binary search. This will not change the overall asymptotic complexity, but for large arrays, the time saving might still be significant.